# sudo with -S still asks for password on the console and clears out whiptail box

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sudo, whiptail

I'm doing some homework for my operative systems class where we have to make a login flow using only bash scripting, I'm having problems as I want to do it with a GUI so I started using whiptail but when I check for the validity of the password entered by the user on the etc/shadow folder, then sudo still asks for the password on the console, even if I pass the password to it using the -S argument. Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
realUser=$(whoami)
user=$(whiptail --title "Change password" --inputbox "Please enter your password" 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
  if [ "$user" == "$realUser" ]
  then
    currentPass=$(whiptail --title "Current Password" --passwordbox "Please enter your current password" 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    exitstatus=$?
    if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
     password=$( sudo -S <<< $currentPass grep -w $realUser /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2)
     userId=$(echo "$password" | cut -f2 -d$)
     userSalt=$(echo "$password" | cut -f3 -d$)
     userPassword=$(echo "$password" | cut -f4 -d$)
     encryptedPass=$(perl -e "print crypt('$currentPass','\$$userId\$$userSalt\$'); \n")
     if [ "$currentPass" == "$encryptedPass" ]
     then
      #Do change the password
 .....
```

The problem is when I execute this command

```
password=$( sudo -S <<< $currentPass grep -w $realUser /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f2)
```

It clears out the whiptail and asks for the user password like sudo would normally do, but isn't `-S <<< $currentPass` passing it the password through stdin so it doesn't have to ask for it?

I don't know if I made my point clear, what I want to do is, using whiptail, ask the user for the username, if the username is the actual logged in user, then ask the user for their password, check if it's the actual user's password and if it is, change their password for a new one they enter.

Comment: Is the command running anyways? `-S` doesn’t prevent a prompt from being written; it just writes it to stderr instead. Try passing `-p ''`, maybe. `-nS` might also work, but I doubt it.

Comment: Tried using -p option but didn't work, there's no prompt but the whiptail box is still cleared